# Iterating optimization on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, optimization

I'm trying to build an iterating interpolation of series `x` and dataframe `y`.
Df `y` is made by `n` rows and `m` columns. I would like to run the interpolation for every row of DataFrame `y`.

So far, I've been able to successfully build the iteration for one single row by using `iloc[0:]`

```
### SX5E
z=np.linspace(0.2,0.99,200)
z_pd_SX5E=pd.Series(z)
from scipy import interpolate
def f(z_pd_SX5E):
    x_SX5E=x
    y_SX5E=y.iloc[0,:]

    tck_SX5E = interpolate.splrep(x_SX5E, y_SX5E)
    return interpolate.splev(z_pd_SX5E, tck_SX5E)
Optimal_trigger_P_SX5E= z_pd_SX5E[f(z_pd_SX5E).argmax(axis=0)]
```

How can I run the function through every row of `y`?
Thanks
Many thanks

Comment: What is `x` and `y` in your code? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi mikksu, x is a series of 9 values and y is a dataframe of 9 columns and 2470 observations.

Comment: basically, I would like to run the function for every row of y.

Comment: x 0    0.19
1    0.29
2    0.39
3    0.49
4    0.59
5    0.69
6    0.79
7    0.89
8    0.99
dtype: float64

Comment: y.      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
Date         
2012-12-18 -0.000395 -0.000159 0.000092 0.000260 0.000188 0.000049 -0.000027 0.000029 0.000035
2012-12-19 -0.000394 -0.000158 0.000092 0.000259 0.000188 0.000049 -0.000027 0.000029 0.000035

Answer (score 0):

In general you can run any function for each row by using `.apply`. So something like:

```
y.apply(lambda val: interpolate.splrep(x,val))
```

This will then return a new series object.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html